# How to run microservice in different docker container in NestJS

Tags: docker, nestjs, microservices

Im creating One main http server and I want to make use of microservices

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport, MicroserviceOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.TCP,
    },
  );
  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
// microservice #1
const microserviceTcp = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    port: 3001,
  },
});
// microservice #2
const microserviceRedis = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.REDIS,
  options: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
  },
});

await app.startAllMicroservices();
await app.listen(3001);
```

But I dont want to start them in one process. I want to run them via docker-compose seaprately in different containers. I want to get rid of
`await app.startAllMicroservices();` and run it myself.
Basically I want every microservice to be run in different container, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to remove `app.startAllMicroservices()` and run microservices app myself. Its working. Im not sure how startAllMicroservices starts these services.